# Why do Hindus worship vehicles on the day of Dussehra?

Tags: belief

Why do Hindus worship vehicles on the day of Dussehra ([vijaya dasami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayadashami))?

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayudha_Puja

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes

Answer (score 1):

It's just a custom to show respect for the technology that has bettered our lives. Hindus of different trades honor their respective tools and implements (a soldier might, for example, honor his weapons).

I think that the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayudha_Puja) sufficiently explains the origins of the custom. Read the first section under the Wikipedia article ("Legend") which explains the two chief mythological and legendary reasons for this puja.